# Can we further refine $\int_{0}^{1}x^{x^x} \ dx=\frac 1 2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac {(n-k)^k}{(k+1)^{n+1}} \binom {n}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**Question**

> Can we further refine the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{x^x}\ dx=\frac 1
>  2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac {(n-k)^k}{(k+1)^{n+1}}
>  \binom {n}{k}$$ ?

To compute the result, first note that $0<x<x^{x^x}<1$ when $0<x<1$. Hence by dominated convergence, supposing that $a>0$, we have

$$\lim_{a \to 0^+}  \int_{0}^{1} x^a x^{x^x}\ dx = \int_{0}^{1}x^{x^x}\ dx $$

and therefore

\begin{align} 
\int_{0}^{1} x^a x^{x^x}\ dx &= \int_{0}^{1} x^a e^{x^x \ln x}\ dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1 {n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^a(x^x \ln x)^n\ dx \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1 {n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}x^a (\log x)^n \frac {(nx \log x)^k}{k!}\ dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {n^k}{n!k!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+a}{(\log x)}^{n+k}\ dx \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {n^k}{n!k!}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{-k-a-2}{(\log t)}^{n+k}\ dt \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^{n+k}n^k}{n!k!(k+1+a)^{n+k+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} u ^{n+k}\ du
\end{align}

where in the last line we made the transformation $(k+1+a) \log t = -u$. Taking the limit $a \to 0^+$ and on further calculations, we get

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{x^x}\ dx=\frac 1 2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac {(n-k)^k}{(k+1)^{n+1}} \binom {n}{k}$$

The result has two summations in the answer. I want to know can we further improve the answer? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I edited your post to (hopefully) make it more clear. I think there is a typo when you introduce the sum over $k$, there are no terms in the integrand with a $k$ index in them.

Comment: Also if k=n in the final equation the last part of the sum becomes 0, so its obsolete to sum from k=1 to n, rather it would be better to just sum to (n-1).

Comment: @Andrew Kovács This is obvious.My question is Can we do something with double sum.

Comment: And it is just a comment not an answer, it is not likely you can do better. Your derivation seems similar of that of Sophomore's dream, so I guess you already know it has no closed form, I suspect this also posesses no closed form.

Comment: There is a slight ambiguity where exponentiation is non-associate. I presume you meant $x^{(x^x)}$ rather than $(x^x)^x$, but please clarify.

Comment: @oliversm Yes, I meant ${x^{(x^x)}}$ rather than $(x^x)^x$

Comment: Alternatively, you could define this as $$\operatorname{Sphd}_3(1, 1, 1;1)$$ as per https://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/attachment.php?aid=788